# Sticky menu works. Sorta

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, sticky

I'm attempting to resolve an issue with a "sticky" horizontal menu.

It technically works, in that the menu's position is fixed while the pages scrolls up and down.

The issue at the moment is that then the page is scrolled back up to the original position, the new resting place of the objects below the sticky menu return to the top of the browser. If that makes sense.

Here's the javascript in use:

```
    <script>
  // When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the navbar
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar_cont");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>
```

And the accompanying css

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + #call-to-action  {
  padding-top:164px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why not give the navbar `position: fixed` all the time? Why make it fixed only when you scroll down? Can you add some of your HTML code and perhaps convert your code example into an executable snippet, or provide a link to a JSFiddle?

Comment: Hi, @PatrickHund. I appreciate the response. I've actually inherited this solution, and I'm not the most experienced javascript user. I have seen online tutorials however that use the same on/off logic. So, this does seem like the standard approach. It's hard to find a good working vanilla js solution for  a sticky menu though. Most seem to be jquery based.